# Symfony add Avatar field to sfGuardUser model

Tags: symfony-1.4, image-uploading, sfguard

I have a project in symfony that I would like to let my users upload an image for their "avatar" field.   I have found many posts about how to "extend" the table which I have with the schema below:

```
Member:
  inheritance:
    type:             column_aggregation
    extends:          sfGuardUser  
columns:
    idmember:    { type: integer }
    birthday:    { type: date }
    avatar:      { type: string(255) }
    bio:         { type: string(255) }
```

The columns get added to the table just fine, but when I go to change the widget to a `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` it breaks.   Here is the Form.class file:

```
  $file_src = $this->getObject()->getAvatar();
  if ($file_src == '')
  {
    $file_src = 'default_image.png';
  }

  $this->widgetSchema['avatar'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
    'label'     => ' ',
    'file_src'  => '/uploads/avatar/'.$file_src,
    'is_image'  => true,
    'edit_mode' => true,
    'template'  => '<div>%file%<br />%input%</div>',
  ));
```

and "save" function of the form:

```
if($this->isModified())
    {
      $uploadDir = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir');
      $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150);
      $thumbnail2 = new sfThumbnail(800, 800);
      if($this->getAvatar())
      {
        $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.'/avatar/'.$this->getAvatar());
        $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'/avatar/thumbnail/'. $this->getAvatar());
        $thumbnail2->loadFile($uploadDir.'/avatar/'.$this->getAvatar());
        $thumbnail2->save($uploadDir.'/avatar/big/'. $this->getAvatar());
      }
   }
```

When I submit the form, I get this error message:

`This form is multipart, which means you need to supply a files array as the bind() method second argument.`

Comment: Can we see the place where you `bind` your form? By the way, I think the `extends` isn't the best way to add value to a sfGuardUser, did you look into the built-in ability to add a Profile to sfGuardUser ? (see [this](http://jmather.com/2010/10/09/customize-sfguarduser-sfdocrineguard/) or [this](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/README#L225))

Comment: j0k thanks for your response.   I have attempted to add a "Profile" to sfGuardUser and I was able to get the table set up, but how do I add the extra fields to the "Register" form so it's seamless to the user and it all shows up on the same form? I tried following this tutorial [HERE](http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin) but it only seems to work with the backend.  Not the frontend "Register" page.  I tried adding an "avatar" widget to the sfGuardUserForm.class.php but it doesn't save the value anywhere when the form is submitted.

Comment: If you use `sfGuardRegisterForm`, it extends `BasesfGuardRegisterForm` which extends `sfGuardUserAdminForm`. And your Profile is defined inside `sfGuardUserAdminForm`. So it might work.

Answer (score 1):

In the **action** where you bind the form you should use something like this:

```
$form->bind($request->getParamater($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
```

So you need to pass the uploaded files as the second parameter to the `bind` method.